# Passing a file argument in Java

Tags: java, file

I am wondering how to pass a `file` as an `argument` on `linux command line`.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println(args[0]);
    }
}
```

For the above code if I do:

```
java -jar myJava.jar blah.txt
```

It prints `blah.txt` to the screen.

But I have a sample line of code that looks like this:

```
java -jar myJava.jar < blah.txt
```

How am I able to get the value of `blah.txt` from the above command?

Comment: Your piping it to stdin.

Comment: Are you just trying to read the file with a `Scanner`? This is an [example that worked on linux](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8627951/java-file-path-in-linux).

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils that was my issue, i didnt understand < was stdin. Thank you for the Scanner idea though, that would have been my next issue im sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use one of the techniques for reading from `System.in` where the file is being redirected such as `Scanner`

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = scanner.nextLine();
    ...
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

try the following

```
java -jar myJava.jar 'blah.txt'
```

The quotes indicate that the argument is literal.

double quotes will also work, but will not prevent things like variable expansion, so single quotes is better when trying to pass a literal string.